# How to calculate tangents of a circle in 3D?

Tags: java, trigonometry, geometry, processing

I need help to calculate the tangets of a circle in 3D space, this is what I have so far
[image]

[image]

Tangents are represented by the blue lines, and this is the method I got from a friend to calculate them

```
Vec3D getTangentBetweenTwoPoint( Vec3D p1, Vec3D p2 ) {
Vec3D r = new Vec3D( p1.x - p2.x,
                     p1.y - p2.y,
                     p1.z - p2.z );
  r.normalize();
  return r;
}

void getTangents() {
  Vec3D p0, p1;
  for ( int i = 1; i < curve_length + 1; i++ ) {
    p0 = points[i % curve_length];
    p1 = points[(i+1) % curve_length];
    tangents[i % curve_length] = getTangentBetweenTwoPoint( p0, p1 );
  }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: As a side note: `i < curve_length + 1` would better be `i <= curve_length` for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you'd find the vector from the point you need the tangent for to the circle's center and take the cross product of that vector as well as the circle's normal (which you get by taking 2 points of the circle plus the center resulting in a plane equation).

If you normalize that cross product you get the normal/tangent vector for that point.

Answer (score 0):

Replace i with i-1 in your code here:

```
p0 = points[(i-1) % curve_length];
```

I am assuming your points are equally spaced on the circle, so the line between the previous point and the next point will be parallel to the tangent at the current point.